# NodeJs program flow

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

Currently still understanding the logic flow of a typical web application. In PHP, since its not async, typically we will have to wait for database insert/update to be completed before returning response to user.

But since in NodeJs we can have Async database query with callback and return response to user even before the callback is being called by database.

In these kind of situation, assuming validation of the data was already done, do typical nodeJs application wait for the callback before response or always assume the query is successful and return response to user?

Comment: You cannot return the response to the client before you receive response from the database (asuming you want to serve the data from db to the client).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking but you should take a look at these explanations of async database queries:

- [Async explanation](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-sync-async-javascript-node/)
- [Callback explanation](http://cwbuecheler.com/web/tutorials/2013/javascript-callbacks/)

If I interpreted your question correctly you are asking when a node application would return a response, right? Typically you return a response to the user (like updating the client view) within the callback. By providing a callback you can make sure that the response is received and successful before moving on in that thread. Here is a bit of code to illustrate:

```
functionThatTakesForever(argument, function(error, response){ //this is the callback
    if(error)
        console.log(error);
    else{
        \\do something with response to return the response to the user
    }
});
```